# AMP validaton error on my website

Tags: amp-html

following errors are showing in amp validation.

1. Invalid CSS stylesheet
2. User-authored JavaScript found on page

[Click Here to access the amp url](https://search.google.com/search-console/amp?utm_source=wmx&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=wmx-agg&id=Zh-rRFSBlEC9mRiNwjvuVg)

Any AMP expert can resolve my issues.

Thanks

Comment: Follow this link : https://ampbyexample.com/

Answer (score 2):

AMP not allowed using **external** `js` or `css` scripts. Also, `inline CSS` is prohibited in it.

For issue
`The mandatory attribute 'action' is missing in tag 'FORM [method=GET]'.`
Define method `get` in this